# Custom hook function not being called in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to call my `fetchPlants` function, but I cannot see to figure out why it is NOT being called.

> /screens/RecipeScreen.js

```
import usePlants from '../hooks/usePlants';

// Call our custom hook
const [fetchPlants, plantResults] = usePlants();

// ...other code...

<RecipeSearch
  recipeSearch={recipeSearch}
  onRecipeSearchChange={setRecipeSearch}
  onRecipeSearchSubmit={() => fetchPlants(recipeSearch)}
/>
```

> /components/RecipeSearch.js

```
const RecipeSearch = ({
  onRecipeSearchChange,
  onRecipeSearchSubmit,
  recipeSearch,
}) => {
  return (
    console.log(recipeSearch); // This prints out nicely...
    <View>
      <View>
        <TextInput
          placeholder='Find a plant...'
          value={recipeSearch}
          onChangeText={onRecipeSearchChange}
          onEndEditing={onRecipeSearchSubmit}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

> /hooks/usePlants.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import plantsApi from '../api/plants';

export default () => {

  const [plantResults, setPlantResults] = useState([]);

  const fetchPlants = async searchTerm => {
    console.log('searchTerm... HERE IS THE QUERY', searchTerm); // this never gets hit
    try {
      const response = await plantsApi.get('').then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        setPlantResults(response);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };


  return [fetchPlants, plantResults];
};
```

I initially thought that maybe I was calling `fetchPlants()` too early (before `recipeSearch` had any state), but I don't think so, because it is still able to `console.log(searchRecipe)` properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** it was working ALL along. When I was testing it with the iOS simulator I needed to hit the "ENTER" key on my computer because I am using the React Native *`onEndEditing`* prop.